# JUnit test case for Java Batch

Tags: junit4, java-batch

We have a existing project which is using Java Batch and we need to write JUnit for that. While searching I am getting examples for Spring Batch but not for Java Batch. Can someone please share an example?

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about Java batch processing based on JSR-352, then a test can be as simple as the following:

- obtain `JobOperator`;
- create job parameters (optional);
- start the job execution by calling `JobOperator.start(jobName, jobParams);
- wait for the job to finish;
- verify job execution status and result, by calling methods on `JobOperator`

An example JUnit test in JBeret: [ClosingReaderWriterTest](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/master/test-apps/chunkClose/src/test/java/org/jberet/testapps/chunk/ClosingReaderWriterTest.java)